# How to append extra data to the existing serializer in django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am new to django rest-framework serializers.

```
views.py 
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])         
def getAllAvailableEmps(request):  
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            roleId = request.GET['emp_role_id']
            getEmp = emp_details.objects.filter(emp_dc_id = None,emp_active = True,emp_role_id = roleId)
            serializer = getEmpDcSerializer(getEmp,many=True)
            return JSONResponse({"allAvilableEmps":serializer.data})
        except Exception as e:
            return JSONResponse("Failure "+str(e)) 

serializers.py
class getEmpDcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = emp_details
        fields = ('emp_id','emp_dc_id','emp_first_name','emp_last_name','emp_role_id')
```

from the above code i got the result like below

```
{
  "allAvilableEmps": [
    {
      "emp_id": 13,
      "emp_dc_id": [],
      "emp_first_name": "aaa",
      "emp_last_name": "bb",
      "emp_role_id": 4
    },
    {
      "emp_id": 16,
      "emp_dc_id": [],
      "emp_first_name": "cccc",
      "emp_last_name": "ddd",
      "emp_role_id": 4
    }
]
}
```

Here,I need to add two more fields(Available,Assign) to the JOSN data.Like below(which is not exist in the database)..
So final JSON should be like below. How to achieve this ?.

```
{
  "allAvilableEmps": [
    {
      "emp_id": 13,
      "emp_dc_id": [],
      "emp_first_name": "aaa",
      "emp_last_name": "bb",
      "emp_role_id": 4
      "Available":1,
      "Assign":2    
    },
    {
      "emp_id": 16,
      "emp_dc_id": [],
      "emp_first_name": "cccc",
      "emp_last_name": "ddd",
      "emp_role_id": 4
      "Available":1,
      "Assign":2    
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can **use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)** to add extra data to the serialized representation of an object.

> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on
>   the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort
>   of data to the serialized representation of your object.

In your serializer, add `Available` and `Assign` `SerializerMethod` fields. Doing this will always add `Available` and `Assign` keys in your serialized data.

```
class getEmpDcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    Available = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # add field
    Assign = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # add field

    class Meta:
        model = emp_details
        fields = ('emp_id','emp_dc_id','emp_first_name','emp_last_name','emp_role_id', 'Available', 'Assign')

    def get_Available(self, obj):
        # here write the logic to compute the value based on object
        return 1

    def get_Assign(self, obj):
        # here write the logic to compute the value based on object
        return 2
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this here instead of as a method on the model?

Comment: One possible use case is if you want to compute value based on `request` or lets say `kwargs`, then you can access these from serializer context and calculate and return final value based on these parameters.