# How to Add JSON Array to DRF Response

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF ListAPIView that returns this:

```
count: 35652
next: "https://platform/events/?format=json&page=2"
previous: null
results: (50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

What do I need to add to the view or serializer to return this?

```
count: 35652
next: "https://platform/events/?format=json&page=2"
previous: null
results: (50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
filter_data: ['filter element 1', 'filter element 2']
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use ListAPIView you can override the `list()` method, bear in mind that this method needs to return a `Response` object (also [take a look](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L37) at the source code) (inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24212269/10028980)).

```
   def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, args, kwargs)

        # you can add the data that you need in the response
        response.data['filter_data'] = ['filter element 1', 'filter element 2']

        return response
```

Also, [don't forget](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#data) that `.data` contains already serialized data.